# Mimic Stackoverflow's effect

Tags: jquery, fadeout

Is there any jquery effect to mimic the fadeout of the background color's fadeout when a new comment displays on the stackoverflow's response wall, ideally with Jquery :)

Comment: jQuery UI's [highlight effect](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/) is close enough, I think.

Answer (score 2):

vanilla jQuery does not allow you to easily animate color, but [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/) adds that ability.

```
$('#foo').animate({ backgroundColor: "#60ffff" }, 1000);
```

Also jQuery UI's [highlight](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/) feature does something close to what you seem to be after:

```
$('#bar').effect("highlight", {}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [jquery-color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) plugin if you don't want to bring all of jQuery UI into your page.